# Added 2 HDD's to my Hyper-V R2 raid and fails to use them (Remote disk management gives RPC server is not available)

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Running Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V (no graphical UI) initially with 3 148GB HDD's RAID5 needing more storage. Added 2 additional 148GB HDD's and, using HP Smart Start, added them to the RAID. Now fails to use Disk Management remotly to make them available for use. Running both the R2 Hyper-V server and the Windows 7 client for remote management in workgroups. Managed to, using hvremote, remotely manage Hyper-V (setting up and run my virtual servers) also I'm allowed to see services but fails to remotlely run disk management. Get "The RPC server is unavailable". Stuck hee - Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first start the Virtual Disk Service (VDS) on the Server Core installation